# share user session between differents mvc projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

In the same solution I have many MVC projects, that use a unique database containing the a common users/passwords table, for all the projects.
I want, if a a user sign in the Url of Project1, this user session stays active in the Url of Project2.
When I refer to user session i do not refer about Session variable, I am talking about user authenticated session
It is possible?

Comment: @SteveGreene: that is a duplicate but not of that one. The OP wants to share authentication (which they call "user sessions") rather than sessions (session container contents).

Comment: exactly, this post is about share values on variable Session, not user authenticated session

Comment: Will they always be hosted within the same domain?

Comment: Yes, the projects are hosted in the same server, same domain, but, in differents virtual directorys, something like http://server/project1.web, http://server/project2.web

Comment: @user1039875: while sharing identity could be possible, you have to specify which MVC you use (mvc5 vs core) and which auth method you use (asp.net identity vs forms auth vs other means of authentication).

Comment: i am using authentication mode="Forms", in all projects...but the projects are mvc4

Comment: The simplest solution would be to combine "multiple projects in one solution" to "a single project in one solution". Each project is a *separate application* when hosted on a web server, so by default they do not share anything. If you put them into a single project then you can share everything including user logons and session state. But if you prefer to do it the hard way, both questions are asked a lot on StackOverflow - do a search.